# Hibernate mapping - Three layer relation in database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, relational-database, hibernate-mapping

I have following relations in my database design: How can I achieve it via hibernate mapping?

I have  a **client** table. every client can have multiple "**facilities**" and also multiple **securities**
also every facility can be covered by multiple securities.

So for example,

> client c1 : has facility F1 F2 F3
> client c1 : has security S1 S2 S3
>
> For this particular client c1 :
> Security S1 covers Facility F1
> Security S2 covers Facility F2
> Security S3 covers Facility F1, F2, F3

So we can have client-facility mapping

> c1 - F1
> c1 - F2
> c1 - F3

and client-security mapping

> c1 - S1
> c1 - S2
> c1 - S3

and we need to have client-facility-security mapping right??

> c1-F1-S1
> c1-F2-S2
> c1-F1-S3
> c1-F2-S3
> c1-F3-S3

Is there any better way of doing this?
Also how can I handle this in hibernate mapping?

I can have many to many mapping for **client-facility** and **client security**
But how can I populate data in **client-facility-security** table using hibernate mapping? or any other solution for given requirement?
Can I have just one table **client-facility-security** and avoid having rest two table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @OneToMany() and @ManyToOne().. To connect Facility with multiple Securities, you can annotate the primary key of Facility with @OneToMany just like how its done in Client class

```
public class Client {

     @Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
 private int id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="facilityReference", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Facilities> facility = new ArrayList<>();


 @OneToMany(mappedBy="securityReference", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Security> security = new ArrayList<>();
      ... Getters and Setters
}


public class Facility {

    private String CLIENT_ID; 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID")
    private Client facilityReference;
}      

public class Security {

      private String CLIENT_ID; 
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID")
      private Client securityReference;}
```

Comment: I have already done this much. But this does not populate client_facility_security table. How can I store client specific details of security-facility mapping?? Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a separate table. If the mapping is defined in the POJOs then it will be taken care..

If you want many to one relation between Facility and Security, then annotate the Facility Primary key with ManyToOne referring Security

ManyToOne
private Security SecurityfacilityReference

Comment: yeah but then it wont be "client" specific.
Facility security mapping is client specific

Comment: @SasukeUchiha
 That will be maintained as you already have built the relation between Client and Facility through OneToMany mapping

Client-Facility - OneToMany
Facility-Security  - ManyToOne
Facility-Client - ManyToOne
Security-Client - ManyToOne